# Combine rows that have different values into one row for the specific value in column A

Tags: google-sheets

I have a big list of items that unfortunately split the items into 2 rows but with differing values in different columns.  Is there a way to combine them into 1 single row like this?

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are never more than two rows with the same key value in column A, you can aggregate the data the way you describe with this formula in cell G1:

```
=query( 
  A1:E, 
  "select A, max(B), max(C), max(D), max(E) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A", 
  0 
)
```